# Error 00368 using arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management

Tags: arcpy, select-by-location

I'm new to programming and I'm having trouble with my script:

```
#Set join parameter variables
inFeatures = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
joinTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
joinField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
#Join road feature class to buffer distance table
arcpy.JoinField_management(inFeatures, inField, joinTable, joinField)
#SCRIPT WORKS TO THIS POINT
#Select roads that intersect the stdsm feature class
stdsM = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(inFeatures, "INTERSECT", stdsM)
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(inFeatures)
```

Running it as a script tool in ArcGIS I get this message:

[image]

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Make sure `inFeatures` is a feature layer (as opposed to a feature class).

Comment: Please always include errors as text rather than pictures do they are available to future searches.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This has me on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

One of your parameters in the call to `arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management()` is not the expected data type.   Step through you code and set a break point right before SelectLayerByLocation.  Inspect the values of parameters `inFeatures`and `stdsM`.  Make sure they are both not null and are the correct type as listed in the [Select layer by Location documentation.](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm)